# Get subscribers total for particular queue

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

How to get subscribers total for a queue?

Somebody help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're talking about the newsletter queue. There is a *Recipients* column in the Newsletter queue grid in the admin.